# How much does a C++11 lambda capture actually capture?

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, lambda

I've seen in multiple examples that you can use a single character to capture multiple variables like the following:

```
Rect rect;
Point point;

auto someLambda = [&](const SomeType& var)
{
    if (rect.Contains(point))
    {
        var.Something();
    }

    this->MemberFunction();
};
```

This ends up grabbing `rect` and `point` by reference and also gives you access to `this`, but how much does it actually capture? Does it only capture the variables that it needs, or does it capture literally everything there is in the current scope?

I've seen in other examples that you can also specify individual variables to capture like this:

```
Rect rect;
Point point;

auto someLambda = [this, &rect, &point](const SomeType& var)
{
    if (rect.Contains(point))
    {
        var.Something();
    }

    this->MemberFunction();
};
```

Is there any advantage to doing it one way or the other? Someone I worked with once mentioned that using the "capture all" `[&]` version was more expensive but I can't find any documentation to back that up. I just want to know for sure so I'm not making code more complex than it needs to be or doing expensive things that I shouldn't be doing.

Comment: Short answer: it captures any variable that is *odr-used* within the lambda

Comment: You should only list individual members if you have no other option due to needing to use different capture methods for some of them.  Using `[&]` lets the compiler figure out which variables are odr-used based on your code; whereas if you try to explicitly list everything then you might list some unnecessary ones, generating inefficient code.

Comment: @M.M On the other hand, from a security perspective, by stating which variables you *intend* to use in the lambda by explicitly capturing _only_ those, there 's less risk that the next dev or even you unintendly manipulates captured data.

Comment: @JohannGerell True, although I'd suggest that if the containing function and the lambda are both so large that it's not immediately obvious whether that happened or not, then the code should be refactored

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda, the capture list (the part in the square braces) is:

> a comma-separated list of zero or more captures, optionally beginning
> with a capture-default. Capture list can be passed as follows [...]:
>
> [a,&b] where a is captured by value and b is captured by reference.
>
> [this] captures the this pointer by value
>
> [&] captures all automatic variables odr-used in the body of
> the lambda by reference
>
> [=] captures all automatic variables odr-used
> in the body of the lambda by value
>
> [] captures nothing

This means that only the automatic (scope-lifetime) variables used in the body of the lambda will be captured.

I can't see why capturing everything with `[&]` would be more expensive than individual captures, but one advantage of listing out the captures explicitly is that there's no chance of capturing something you didn't expect.

On the other hand, capturing with `[=]` could prove expensive since it will make copies of everything. Perhaps that's what your coworker was referring to.

Comment: Oh wow, I don't know how I missed that page. I use cppreference all the time. I think you're right on that last point. I actually didn't know you could do `[&]` to capture everything by reference until I saw it in some code recently. I don't think either of us knew about it so it was probably the `[=]` that was the culprit. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: The _"no chance of capturing something you didn't expect."_ is important

Answer (score 1):

> This ends up grabbing rect and point by reference and also gives you access to this, but how much does it actually capture?

When you capture with `[&]` it captures all the variables in the body of the lambda that have **automatic storage duration** and are odr-used.

Here is an example:

```
int main()
{
    int num = 50;
    [&] { std::cout << num << '\n'; }(); // num captured by reference
    [=] { std::cout << num << '\n'; }(); // num captured by value

    [&num] { std::cout << num << '\n'; }(); // by reference
    [num] { std::cout << num << '\n'; }();  // by value
}
```

If you know that you will only capture one variable, you don't need to capture everything by value / reference.

But on the other hand, if you know that you will be capturing a few variables, capturing them with `[&]` or `[=]` is easier than typing them all out.